# Disable white flash during SharedElementTransition

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

Is it possible to disable the white flash which appears during Shared Element Transitions? I have a dark theme in my Android app, and the white flash makes the app unpleasant to use whenever there's a transition.
While there were some questions regarding this issue, I couldn't solve this problem in my app so far.

(e.g. the cause for the blinking was in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567454/android-lollipop-shared-elements-transition-blink-flash) a NavigationDrawerLayout, but my transition gets started in my Activity after a view been clicked in a Fragment)

styles.xml

```
    <!-- enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

This method starts a new transition in my Activity

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void startItemDetailActivityTransition(Item pItem, boolean pForceComments, View pTransitionView) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemDetailActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, Pair.create(pTransitionView, getString(R.string.transition_item)));
    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailActivity.EXTRA_ITEM, pItem);
    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailActivity.EXTRA_FORCE_COMMENTS, pForceComments);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try excluding the parts which have the white flash like this

```
        Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.excludeTarget(R.id.p1,true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    }
```