# Background Glitch while using shared elements

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I am having two activities,out which first activity contain a recycle view in fragment which is added on the first activity and second activity contain a toolbar in collapsing toolbar layout,i have created a shared element transition between this two activities when a user click on a any Recycle view item which contains a image which i want to use as shared element to the second activity's toolbar image.i have set the transition like this.

**First Activity**

```
ChangeBounds changebound=new ChangeBounds();
changebound.setDuration(500);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(changebound);
```

**Second Activity**

```
ChangeBounds changebound=new ChangeBounds();
changebound.setDuration(500);
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(changebound);
```

I am Staring Second Activity from Recycler view `onItemClick`of the first activity like this

```
Pair<View, String> imagePair=Pair.create(itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgChannelImage), activity.getResources().getString(R.string.channel_name));
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putInt("Position", getLayoutPosition());
    mBundle.putString("ChannelName", "One Direction " +getLayoutPosition());
    Intent i = new Intent(activity, ProChannelPageActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(mBundle);   
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context,imagePair);
    activity.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

I am able to have shared element transition between this two.but the problem is having a background glitch i.e we able to see the first activity background for few fraction while image view moving from one activity to another.

Comment: Have you set any background for your first activity xml file?

Comment: Also please add screenshot how it looks?

Comment: Did you refer this link http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html?

Comment: See this link for the solution to a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588085/5060269

Answer (score -1):

I can understand your problem.
Basically what is happening is that, you are only sharing the 2 Views you have mentioned. But the Status Bar on the Top, the Navigation Bar on the Bottom (and maybe others, in your case)do not get shared. So it seems like a blink.

You can see this post, see if it helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748694/2346980